# Looping over each row and comparing values in multiple columns of the row being iterated

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe `yearly`

```
ID   Jan Feb March April May Jun Jul Aug Sept Oct Nov Dec
ABC   0  0    0     1    0   0    0   0  1     0   0  0
DEF   0  0    0     1    1   0    0   0  1     0   0  0
GHI   0  0    0     1    0   1    0   0  0     1   0  0
MNO   0  0    0     1    0   1    0   0  1     0   0  0
QAL   0  1    1     1    0   0    1   0  0    1   0  0
```

I want to iterate through each row and then find that column after which the three columns are 0. I would like to get something like this which says the months after where there are no 0s for at least 3 months:

```
ID    col1    col2 
ABC   April   Sept  
DEF   May     Sept 
GHI   Jun      N/A
MNO   Sept    N/A
QAL   N/A     N/A
```

I had figured out how to iterate through the vector and get the index

```
vec2 <- names(yearly)
# vec is each row of yearly 
  for(i in 1:length(vec)){
if(vec[i]==1){
  if(vec[i+1]+vec[i+2]+vec[i+3]==0){  #I think R automatically takes care of the out of bounds index
    print(vec2[1])
    print(vec2[i+1])
  }
}
 }
    }
  }
```

But I am finding it a bit difficult to link it to the original dataframe and get the columns. Any functions or resources that can guide me ?

Comment: why is GHI not JUN, OCT ???

Comment: After OCT, You need 3 0s but there are only  2 0s

Comment: Okay, I just got that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there are a variable number of answers per row, I'd opt for a list. This approach uses `rle` to find runs of zeroes, then checks if there are more than 2 in the run. It then returns the names of the months preceding these runs.

```
# Data
df <- read.table(text = "ID   Jan Feb March April May Jun Jul Aug Sept Oct Nov Dec
ABC   0  0    0     1    0   0    0   0  1     0   0  0
           DEF   0  0    0     1    1   0    0   0  1     0   0  0
           GHI   0  0    0     1    0   1    0   0  0     1   0  0
           MNO   0  0    0     1    0   1    0   0  1     0   0  0
           QAL   0  1    1     1    0   0    1   0  0    1   0  0",
           header = TRUE)

# Repackage as list (rows become elements of list)
df_list <- setNames(split(df[, -1], seq(nrow(df))), rownames(df$ID))

# Count function
morpheus_count <- function(x){
  #Run Length Encoding
  tmp <- rle(x)

  # Return months preceding a run of three (or greater) zeroes
  names(tmp$values)[which(tmp$values==0 & tmp$lengths>2)-1]
}

# Run on list
lapply(df_list, morpheus_count)
```

Results:

```
# [[1]]
# [1] "April" "Sept" 
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "May"  "Sept"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "Jun"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "Sept"
# 
# [[5]]
# character(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are different approaches to tackle the problem:

#### String matching

This approach uses string matching and thus relies on the values to be of character length one:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

yearly[, 
       {
         Reduce(paste0, .SD) %>% 
           stringr::str_locate_all("1000") %>% 
           as.data.table()
       }, 
       .SDcols = -"ID", by = "ID"][
         , .(ID, month = names(yearly)[start + 1L])]
```

> ```
>     ID month
> 1: ABC April
> 2: ABC  Sept
> 3: DEF   May
> 4: DEF  Sept
> 5: GHI   Jun
> 6: MNO  Sept
> ```

This can be reshaped into wide format as requested by the OP:

```
yearly[, 
       {
         Reduce(paste0, .SD) %>% 
           stringr::str_locate_all("1000") %>% 
           as.data.table()
       }, 
       .SDcols = -"ID", by = "ID"][
         , .(ID, month = names(yearly)[start + 1L])][
           , dcast(.SD, ID ~ rowid(ID, prefix = "col"))][
             yearly[, ID], on = "ID"]
```

> ```
>     ID  col1 col2
> 1: ABC April Sept
> 2: DEF   May Sept
> 3: GHI   Jun <NA>
> 4: MNO  Sept <NA>
> 5: QAL  <NA> <NA>
> ```

#### Join columns in a rolling window in wide format

This approach is somewhat similar to the string matching approach. It finds matches by an inner join of four subsequent columns which are moved in a rolling window across the columns of `yearly`, i.e., it tries to find matches in columns `Jan, Feb, March, April`, then in columns `Feb, March, April, May`, and so on, and finally in columns `Sept, Oct, Nov, Dec`.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
# pattern to find matches
tmp <- data.table(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, month = "")
# column 1 is the ID column
lapply(2:10, function(x) 
{ # rename col names for join of subsequent columns
  setnames(tmp, 1:4, names(yearly)[x:(x+3)])
  # append starting month of sequence
  tmp[, month := names(yearly)[x]]
  # inner join
  yearly[tmp, on = head(names(tmp), -1L), .(ID, month), nomatch = 0L]
}) %>% 
  # convert list to data.table
  rbindlist() %>% 
  # reshape to wide format and append missing ID rows
  dcast(ID ~ rowid(ID, prefix = "col")) %>% 
  .[yearly[, ID], on = "ID"]
```

> ```
>     ID  col1 col2
> 1: ABC April Sept
> 2: DEF   May Sept
> 3: GHI   Jun <NA>
> 4: MNO  Sept <NA>
> 5: QAL  <NA> <NA>
> ```

#### Data

```
yearly <- fread(
"ID   Jan Feb March April May Jun Jul Aug Sept Oct Nov Dec
ABC   0  0    0     1    0   0    0   0  1     0   0  0
DEF   0  0    0     1    1   0    0   0  1     0   0  0
GHI   0  0    0     1    0   1    0   0  0     1   0  0
MNO   0  0    0     1    0   1    0   0  1     0   0  0
QAL   0  1    1     1    0   0    1   0  0     1   0  0"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

data:

```
df<-data.table::fread("
ID   Jan Feb March April May Jun Jul Aug Sept Oct Nov Dec
ABC   0  0    0     1    0   0    0   0  1     0   0  0
DEF   0  0    0     1    1   0    0   0  1     0   0  0
GHI   0  0    0     1    0   1    0   0  0     1   0  0
MNO   0  0    0     1    0   1    0   0  1     0   0  0
QAL   0  1    1     1    0   0    1   0  0     1   0  0") %>% setDF
```

code:

```
library(magrittr)
rowNames <- df[,1,drop=T]
months   <- names(df[,-1])
fun1<-function(x) {
    n      <- 3 #at least 3 zeros (change if needed)
    pos    <- c(-1,cumsum(x)) %>% diff %>% as.logical %>% which
    counts <- table(cumsum(x)) %>% as.numeric %>% {. > n & as.logical(x[pos])}
    return(months[pos[counts]])
}

res <- apply(df[,-1],1,fun1)
names(res) <- rowNames
```

result:

```
$ABC
[1] "April" "Sept" 

$DEF
[1] "May"  "Sept"

$GHI
[1] "Jun"

$MNO
[1] "Sept"

$QAL
character(0)
```

please note:

- make sure data is of type `data.frame`.
- make sure you apply `fun1` only on the `0,1` data. That's why `df[,-1]` is called.
- you can change the `n` inside `fun1` for other criteria.